# Erro ao ler todos os registros de um arquivo.txt em C

Tags: c, arquivo, txt, biblioteca

Alguém sabe me dizer porque esse meu código apenas retorna o primeiro registro várias vezes, ao invés de retorna todos os registros?

**Função no Código**

```
void listarDados(int quantidadeContatos) {
    char caracteres;
    FILE *arquivo = fopen("contato.txt", "rb");
    struct contato *vPtrContato = &contato_ref;

    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
    } else {
        while (!feof(arquivo)) { 
            rewind(arquivo); 
            fread(vPtrContato, sizeof (contato_ref), 1, arquivo);
            printf("Nome: %s\n", contato_ref.primeiroNome);
            printf("Sobrenome: %s\n", contato_ref.segundoNome);
            printf("Telefone: %s\n", contato_ref.numeroTelefone);
            printf("E-mail: %s\n", contato_ref.email);
            printf("==================================\n");
            fclose(arquivo);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função rewind() (falando grosseiramente) serve para retornar ao começo do arquivo, ou seja fread passa adiante mas o rewind volta para o começo.

Comment: Tirei o rewind e mesmo assim ainda retorna apenas o primeiro registro. Só que repetidas vezes.

Comment: Não havia visto, você fecha o arquivo dentro do while, apague a linha do fclose() e veja.

Answer (score 0):

Código com a listagem completa de todos os registros do arquivo txt

```
void listarDados() {
    FILE *arquivo = fopen("contato.txt", "rb");
    struct contato *vPtrContato = &contato_ref;

    /*se o arquivo nao existir, mostra msg de erro*/
    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
    } else {
        /*caso o arquivo exista, leia-o ate o fim do arquivo*/
        printf("==================================\n");
        printf("Resultado da pesquisa\n");
        printf("==================================\n");
        while (!feof(arquivo)) { //enquanto não chegar no fim do arquivo, continue lendo
            /*funcao para ler arquivo
             referencia do elemento que sera lido, que no caso e a referencia d struct
             * a quantidade de dados que sera lida, que no caso e o tamanho da struct
             * referencia do arquivo
             */

            fread(vPtrContato, sizeof (contato_ref), 1, arquivo);

            printf("Nome: %s\n", contato_ref.primeiroNome);
            printf("Sobrenome: %s\n", contato_ref.segundoNome);
            printf("Telefone: %s\n", contato_ref.numeroTelefone);
            printf("E-mail: %s\n", contato_ref.email);
            printf("===================================\n");
        }
        fclose(arquivo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

O problema está sendo causada pela função rewind, pois ela possui o papel de voltar para o começo do arquivo.